# Connect pressure gauge value with java Netbeans

Tags: java

Is it possible to display a value read from a digital pressure gauge in a `txtfield` in Netbeans? The pressure gauge is connected to a computer via USB port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.

First you need to build a basic java application that can read from a file (or text file) and display that information in a textfield or some similar control.

Then you need to find out through reading technical documentation of the digital gauge how it communicates with your computer and make it write its current data to a file (or text file). Once you have that you just make your Java program read from that file. With little luck your gauge will write to some file by default.

**Edit:** If you want to display some data in Netbeans, as in the IDE itself then, you should look into building plugins / extensions for your IDE of choice. Displaying data in its GUI should be a popular topic on IDE plugin tutorials.